# Join array of strings in d

Tags: string, d

In python I can do this:

```
In [1]: x = ["a", "b", "c"]

In [2]: "--".join(x)
Out[2]: 'a--b--c'
```

Is there an equivalent trick in d?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, use [`std.array.join`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_array.html#.join):

```
import std.array, std.stdio;

void main()
{
    auto x = ["a", "b", "c"];
    writeln(x.join("--"));
}
```

Note that D's argument order is reversed when compared to Python's.

Comment: In D argument order is natural. In Python it is reversed.